# document.scrollTop coming 0 in Ionic

Tags: jquery, angular, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

When I scroll my page and click, I get its **y position** from the top, so as I scroll it keeps on increasing in HTML and JS.

But when I am trying to achieve the same in Ionic it is always returning **0**.

For more clarity see this [1 minute video](http://youtu.be/T7M2JCV46u4?hd=1).

Below is my working jsfiddle code, link to my [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/r1xgwkyd/2236/) , scroll and click, you will see alert with y position value.

```js
       $("body").click(function(){
       var scrollPost = $(document).scrollTop();
       alert(scrollPost);
       })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="conta"></div>
  The world is your oyster.
  test<br/><br/><br/><br/>kjh<br/>kjgh<br/>uitz<br/><br/><br/><br/>uztjhg<br/>kjh<br/>
  test<br/><br/><br/><br/>kjh<br/>kjgh<br/>uitz<br/><br/><br/><br/>uztjhg<br/>kjh<br/>test<br/><br/><br/><br/>kjh<br/>kjgh<br/>uitz<br/><br/><br/><br/>uztjhg<br/>kjh<br/>test<br/><br/><br/><br/>kjh<br/>kjgh<br/>uitz<br/><br/><br/><br/>uztjhg<br/>kjh<br/>test<br/><br/><br/><br/>kjh<br/>kjgh<br/>uitz<br/><br/><br/><br/>uztjhg<br/>kjh<br/>test<br/><br/><br/><br/>kjh<br/>kjgh<br/>uitz<br/><br/><br/><br/>uztjhg<br/>kjh<br/>test<br/><br/><br/><br/>kjh<br/>kjgh<br/>uitz<br/><br/><br/><br/>uztjhg<br/>kjh<br/>test<br/><br/><br/><br/>kjh<br/>kjgh<br/>uitz<br/><br/><br/><br/>uztjhg<br/>kjh<br/>
  <div class="test">Thats a test</div>
```

How can I achieve the same in Ionic, this is not working. Here is my [Stackblitz link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-ltiafz).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you should never use jQuery with Angular, they do the same thing so there's no use to have both, everything jQuery does Angular can do too. So it's not recommended. So unless it's extremely needed, don't use.

You can't observe any changes to your `scrollTop` property since it's not moving the `body`, but it's moving the content tag inside of it. There's an `content` [component](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/content/Content/) whose ou can use to get this property. So do this:

Your page .ts

```
import { Component, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { Content } from 'ionic-angular';

@Component({...})
export class MyPage{
  @ViewChild(Content) content: Content;
  public scrollPost: number = 0;

  getScrollTop() {
    this.scrollPost = this.content.scrollTop;
  }
}
```

Your HTML:

```
<ion-content (ionScroll)="getScrollTop()">
  <!-- your page content -->
</ion-content>
```

With this you'll always change the value of `scrollPost` with the value scrolled, but if you need to use this value anywhere with a click don't just add a click to your `ion-content` or any click to any element inside of it will not work, instead use a button or do what you need to do inside `getScrollTop` method.

Hope this helps.

Comment: noted, there is 1 error when i am trying the above solution on line ` this.scrollPost = this.content.scrollTop();` , see my stackblitz, this is editor link - https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-ltiafz  , please guide

Comment: @user2828442 oh, i'm so sorry, `scrollTop` is a property of the content and not a function, just remove the function execution on the end of it and everything works fine. Updated my answer.

Comment: and how do i get the scrollTop value of where i clicked ? as i want to open contextmenu there

Comment: @user2828442 you can add a `click` to some element passing an event like `(click)="myMethod($event)` and in that method there's a property of the Y and X coordinates on the screen where the user clicked, just don't remember the properties name correctly, but just `console.log()` the event and they're easy to find.

Answer (score 0):

While using Ionic you don't scroll the whole document.
You should check the element's scroll positions with class `scroll-content`.

```
console.log(document.querySelector('.scroll-content').scrollTop);
```

There are some cases when you have more than one `scroll-content`, so you could iterate on them like:

```
const scrollContents = document.querySelectorAll('.scroll-content');
for (let i = 0; i < scrollContents.length; ++i) {
    console.log(scrollContents.length[i].scrollTop);
    // do something
}
```

Comment: Due you mean, i should add the class 'scroll-content' to my div which has class 'conta' ?

Comment: No, the Ionic automaticlly add that.